# C# Error - The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, url, stream, webrequest

My issue is the following. I want to read the source code of a certain website using the code below. That works fine with the base url for example "https://url.com".

But if I want to get the sourcecode of the "childurl" for example "https://url.com/userstatistics" it gives me an error: "The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly".

After visiting that url manually using my Browser which works, I am also able to use the code below to return the sourcecode from that url for the next 30 seconds. One minute later if I try again (without opening it manually in browser) it gives me that error again.

Why is that happening? Is there something I can do about that? Does the Website has some sort of sourcecode protection which I can bypass somehow?

My code looks like this:

```
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        string urlAddress = "https://url.com";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); //Error occurs here!

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.CharacterSet))
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            else
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));

            Responsecode = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(Responsecode);

            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use HttpClient instead? WebRequest is kind of a legacy of the .NET Framework. Provide exception details, please: it will be useful, because you don't share the url.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to the way you've initialised **readStream**

try:

```
Stream responseStream;
```

or

```
StreamReader responseStream;
```

Comment: Setting it to Null in this case would cause you to dispose your response object before reading from its stream